# How to calculate different matrix representation from the same permutation group?

Tags: representation-theory

How to calculate 2 dimension representation, unitary representation, 3 dimension representation etc

tips: my book teach to use schmidt to calculate

Comment: Just how this is related to GAP or Maple? I am going to remove those tags, unless the question will be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The complex representation theory of the symmetric groups is well known. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group

for details.

Comment: could you show an example of calculation?